# how to invoke an pop up window using javascript that gets populated with an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, popupwindow

I have the following code in a java class to add a link to a table grid. The following code is specific to the company's internal API.

```
  /***MyLink.java*********/

  myLink.setOnClick( "getURL", return false;);
  addToolBarItem("myLink");

  /***MyLinkJSFPage.jsf****

  urlValue= "www.google.com";
```

In the jsf page i have to make an ajax request to the getURL javascript which would open an popup window with an url from the jsf page. Basically,when the user clicks on the link, a javascript popup window should get populated with an ajax request. How do we do it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that instead of a popup window, I prefer to use a  element to achieve the same effect, since most browsers these days have popup blockers.  With a div "popup", there is nothing that will block it.

First, you need to have the div in your HTML code.  Anywhere is fine.  This is the area where your content will be shown.  It must have an id tag (in this case, "popup")

```
<div id='popup' style='visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 300px;'></div>
```

Next you need the javascript code that will request the page and receive the response from the server.  This is my standard function:

```
function get_(url, func)
{
 var http;
 try { http = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { alert(\"Failed to load!\"); return false; } } }

 http.open(\"GET\", url, true);
 http.onreadystatechange = function() { if(http.readyState == 4) { func(http); } }
 http.send(null);
}
```

For this example, I will just have a button cause the popup to function so that you can see how to use the code.  Here is everything all together:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'><!--

function get_(url, func)
{
 var http;
 try { http = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { try { http = new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\"); } catch (e) { alert(\"Your browser broke!\"); return false; } } }

 http.open(\"GET\", url, true);
 http.onreadystatechange = function() { if(http.readyState == 4) { func(http); } }
 http.send(null);
}

function getPopup()
{
 get_("url_of_popup_source.html", showPopup);
}

function showPopup(h)
{
 var p = document.getElementById("popop");
 p.innerHTML = h.responseText;
 p.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hidePopup()
{
 p.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

--></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onClick='showPopup();'>Click here</button>
<div id='popup' style='visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 300px; top:100px; left:200px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is obviously very basic.  You can adjust the size of the popup and the absolute position too.  But the main idea is that you are no longer using an actual popup window to get the information to the user, since it might be bloacked anyways.

The extra function I included "hidePopup" will close the popup.  I would recommend that you include a button in your "url_of_popup_source.html" source a button that executes hidePopup when clicked.  that way, the user can read the information, then close the popup as if it was a dialog box.